# Does PHP supercede jQuery in any way?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation

I have some jQuery validation code I'm trying to apply to a form at this page:  https://www.kevinmangles-magician.com/bookings.php. So I'm using jQuery with a PHP based website.

We're getting some empty forms returned despite the default validation and this app.js code should be fixing it. But the validation is not working.

I have the form being sent to **sendmail.php** in my code. The jQuery should stop it if there are any invalid or empty fields.  There are no JS console errors but the class "needs-filled" is not being added to any fields.

```
/*Form Validation*/
/*
Created 09/27/09                                        
Questions/Comments: jorenrapini@gmail.com                       
COPYRIGHT NOTICE        
Copyright 2009 Joren Rapini
*/  

//  contact_name, email, message, accept

// Place ID's of all required fields here.
required = ["contact_name", "e_mail", "message", "accept"];
// If using an ID other than #email or #error then replace it here
email = $("#e_mail");
errornotice = $("#error");


// The text to show up within a field when it is incorrect
emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";
emailerror = "Please enter a valid e-mail.";

$("#contact-form").submit(function(){   
    //Validate required fields
    for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
        var input = $('#'+required[i]);
        if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
            input.addClass("needs-filled");
            input.val(emptyerror);
            errornotice.fadeIn(750);
        } else {
            input.removeClass("needs-filled");
        }
    }
    // Validate the e-mail.
    if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.val())) {
        email.addClass("needs-filled");
        email.val(emailerror);
    }

    //if any inputs on the page have the class 'needsfilled' the form will not submit
    if ($(":input").hasClass("needs-filled")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        errornotice.hide();
        return true;
    }
}); 

// Clears any fields in the form when the user clicks on them
$(":input").focus(function()  {     
    if ($(this).hasClass("needs-filled") ) {
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).removeClass("needs-filled");

        $("p").click(function() {
            $("#error").remove();
        });
    }
});
```

I'm expecting Red filled input boxes on the linked form and error messages within thwm.

Comment: client-side != server-side, you need to validate both sides

Comment: BTW your email validation is very restrictive. There are so many addresses which would fail this validation.

Comment: Any validation you do on the client side is ***purely*** as a courtesy to the user. It is trivial to work around it, so you absolutely *have* to perform all business critical validation in your server side logic.